# Sound not playing out of headphones for specific steam games only

Tags: windows-10, audio, gaming, headphones, steam

I have Razer Man O' War headphones that work fine for literally everything except a select few steam games (e.g. Hollow Knight, Cuphead, Getting Over It, Ori and the Blind Forest).  I can listen to music, watch Youtube videos, play other games, everything works, but for some reason when I try to play these games the sound doesn't play through my headphones.  I can switch to my computer's speakers and the sound plays, if I plug in earphones into the earphone slot the sound plays (I think this works because it just replaces the computer speakers directly, and I don't even have to change output device for earbuds), but with my headphones, no sound whatsoever.  Other steam games play sound (for example, PUBG, Stardew Valley, and Papers, Please all work fine), and I can't see why only a few of my games have this problem.  I could just buy some earphones, but I'd rather fix this problem if possible.  I'm on Windows 10.0.16299.

Comment: Well, it's definitely not worth playing Ori until your sound is working...Even though they may be all on Steam, the games are separate executables so that probably has nothing to do with Steam. Have you checked the Volume Mixer and Playback Devices, while a game is running?

Comment: yup, playback device is correct and sound is turned up in the volume mixer.